# taking String of controller to the textarea using servlet

Tags: java, html

I have this code

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                   <form class="form-horizontal" action="ChatController">

                    <textarea name="bottxt" id="disabledTextInput" border="2" class="form-control col-xs-6" rows="8" cols="60"></textarea><br>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="usertxt" placeholder="your text here">
                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success active"> Send </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

So i have ChatController. I want to return a string every time user types something in TextBox and press "submit". How can i do that .

Comment: Where is your closing </form> tag? Your code seems ok. When user type something & press submit button, it will send value to concerned servlet. Have you coded that.

Comment: Nope i require that part

Comment: I can give you that. Just tell me one thing. Do you want your text to be displayed in that small text box where you have written "your text here". What is the role of it.

Comment: user will input some text in the textbox and the system will reply it in textarea i created.

Comment: You mean you want user to type text in that small text box and you want tot display that text at same time int textarea. If this is it why have you put textarea within form. You should have put the small text box within form. If I am not correct, do clarify it.

Comment: In my new code it is. can you help me How can i return the text that is generated from the servlet i will be creating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have understood from our conversation here is your answer. First we have to convert your html page to jsp page because only jsp page can receive response send in form of request dispatcher from servlet. Here it is  :-

```
//textView.jsp
<%@page import="model.TextBean"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="row">
                <%
                TextBean txt=new TextBean();
                txt=(TextBean)request.getAttribute("txt");
                String text="";
                if(txt!=null && txt.getText()!=null){
                    text=txt.getText();
                }
                %>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <textarea name="bottxt" id="disabledTextInput" border="2" class="form-control col-xs-6" rows="8" cols="60"><%=text%></textarea><br>
                        <form class="form-horizontal" action="ChatController" method="post">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="usertxt" placeholder="your text here">
                        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success active"> Send </button>
                       </form>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Then we receive the value sent from this page in a servlet. But first we have to design a java class called TextBean. Its text variable will store the value of text entered.

```
package model;

public class TextBean {
    String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

In our servlet we assign the value received from jsp page to this bean. Then we use request dispatcher to send response back to the jsp page in form of attribute.

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import model.TextBean;

public class ChatController extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String text=request.getParameter("usertxt");
        TextBean txt=new TextBean();
        txt.setText(text);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("textView.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("txt", (TextBean)txt);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

In jsp page we create a new TextBean and set it to the value received from servlet. Then using getter method from bean we store the text in a string variable and then display it in textarea. If it is what you want mark the problem solved by clicking right mark in left side of my answer. If it is not let me know. Happy Coding :)